# Field on Poincaré disk

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, metric-spaces, field-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

Is there a known normed field on the Poincaré disk?

The distance ($\left\lVert{z - w}\right\rVert$) must be identical to the Poincaré metric.

As far as I know, it is not isometric to the complex plane.

I want to know this because I want to see if trigonometric functions could be defined on infinite points.

Comment: If you mean the "norm" is the distance to $0$ then send $z\in \Bbb{D}$ to $\frac{d(0,z)}{|z|}z\in \Bbb{C}$

Comment: @reuns How are the binary operations (addition and multiplication) defined?

Comment: Do you mean $f : \Bbb{D}\to K$ is bijective, $\|f(z)-f(w)\|=d(z,w)$ and $\|a+b\|\le \|a\|+\|b\|$ and $\|ra\|= |r| \|a\|$ for $r\in \Bbb{Q}$ ? If so by continuity of $f,f^{-1}$ then $K$ contains $\Bbb{R}$ so it is a real vector space then it is clear it must be of dimension 2 thus to be a field $K=\Bbb{C}$, a contradiction since its norm is flat. Another argument : $\|ra\|= |r| \|a\|$ implies the curvature (the $\epsilon^4$ term of $Vol(d(z_0,.)<\epsilon)$) is $0$.

Comment: @reuns Exactly. Would you post that as an answer? Further explanation is appreciated.